# Animating superposed elements with CSS Animations

Tags: css, animation

Hi StackOverflow community,

I am trying to produce an "Orbit" on-hover animation, where a number of div elements are stacked on top of one another and they have different sizes so I can play with the borders circling around the "planet" (ie: main element).

My problem though is that it seems like when I stack one div over another and both are supposed to be animated, only the front element plays the animation and not those under.

I thought a z-index property could fix this, but as I thought about this I just thought I'd be switching one animation for the other, since the one I'd elevate with the z-index would then become the front and cover the one element that's now below.

Here's some code:

```css
#spinner {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* -- -- -- Spin Animation -- -- -- */

#spinner-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: black;
  border-bottom-color: black;
}

#spinner-1:hover {
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg) scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
  }
}

/* -- -- -- Orbit Ring -- -- -- */

#spinner-4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #333;
  border-bottom-color: #333;
  border-left-color: #333;
}

#spinner-4:hover {
  animation: spin-2 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin-2 {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    }
    50% {
      transform: rotate(-180deg) scale(1.3);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotate(-360deg) scale(1);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="spinner">
  <div id="spinner-1"></div>
  <div id="spinner-4"></div>
</div>
```

So, basically I want both spinner-1 and spinner-4 to execute their animation when I hover over the spinner. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the hover on their shared parent element.

```css
#spinner {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* -- -- -- Spin Animation -- -- -- */

#spinner-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: black;
  border-bottom-color: black;
}

#spinner:hover #spinner-1 {
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg) scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
  }
}


/* -- -- -- Orbit Ring -- -- -- */

#spinner-4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #333;
  border-bottom-color: #333;
  border-left-color: #333;
}

#spinner:hover #spinner-4 {
  animation: spin-2 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin-2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg) scale(1.3);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg) scale(1);
  }
}


}
```

```html
<div id="spinner">
  <div id="spinner-1"></div>
  <div id="spinner-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, it worked. Thank you so much! Have a great day!

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to mark this answer as correct.